# Python: Unexpected string comparison result: True != True

Tags: python, django, string, comparison

I´ve been researching this issue in SO but could not find a similar one.

Here is my problem:
I have a JSON-String that I serialize like this

```
data = json.loads(data)
attr = data['data']
```

In this dataset there are two attributes, lets call them @attr1 and @attr2. Here is my test code to show the problem:

```
print('///')
print(attr['@attr1'])  # where attr['@attr1'] is a string and either 'True' (sometimes also 'true') or 'False'
print('+++')
print(attr['@attr2']) # where attr['@attr2'] is a string and either '1' or '0'
print('///')

if attr['@attr1'] == 'True' or attr['@attr1'] == 'true':
    print('As True:')
    print(attr['@attr1'])
else:
    print('As NOT True:')
    print(attr['@attr1'])
if attr['@attr2'] == '1':
    print('As 1:')
    print(attr['@attr2'])
else:
    print('As NOT 1:')
    print(attr['attr2'])
```

The output of this script is:

```
# OUTPUT:

///
True
+++
1
///
As NOT True:
True
As NOT 1:
1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `print(repr(attr['@attr1']))` to check the string is actually what you think it is.

Comment: Argh. There is still so much to learn. That was actually it. It was a bool and an int. Thanks for your prompt help -- highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all, check the type of the attributes with, i.e. `print(type(data[...]))`.
Maybe your data is *boolean* `True` and integer `1`.

If the types is different from `str`, comparison result if `False`, because python doesn't do type casting/coercion implicitly (unlike, say, JS).

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was it. I did not know, that python would convert the "string" to a boolean by it self. You really helped me out of some serious confusion :). Thank you very much Sir!

Comment: You are welcome, but note here – python does _not_ convert strings to boolean for you. You have json file, where booleans encoded as booleans, by json standard. You may look at https://www.json.org/ for reference on "available" types.